# Log out from chrome using windows authentication and close chrome tab

Tags: asp.net

I used the below code as mentioned above to log out from chrome in windows authentication and redirect it to log out page but it is not working for me.

Please help me

function logout() {
        try
        {
            var agt = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();

```
        //if (document.all)
        {
            if (agt.indexOf("msie") != -1)  // IE clear HTTP Authentication
            {
                alert("IE");
                document.execCommand("ClearAuthenticationCache");
                alert("You have successfully logged out");
                window.open('', '_self', '');
                window.close();
            }
            else {
                alert("Not IE");
                // Let's create an xmlhttp object
                var xmlhttp = createXMLObject();
                xmlhttp.open("GET", "Logout.aspx", true, "logout", "logout");

                // Let's send the request to the server
                xmlhttp.send("");
                // Let's abort the request
                xmlhttp.abort();


            }

        }
    }
    catch (e)
    {
    }
}
function createXMLObject() {
    try {
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
            // code for IE
        else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
    } catch (e) {
        xmlhttp = false
    }
    return xmlhttp;
}
```

the issue is it is not getting logged out.

Comment: when you say not working, what is not working? what is the error? witch line or part is "not working"?